# Integer Part of sequence convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was trying to solve the following exercise.

If $(a_n) \in \mathbb{R}$ and $(a_n)\rightarrow {1}/{2}$ show that $[a_n] \rightarrow 0$ , where $[~]$ the integer part.

I was trying to solve it using the ε-definition. $\forall ε>0 ~ \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N} : |a_n - 1/2|< ε ~,~~ \forall n \geq  n_0$.

I want $\forall ε>0 ~ \exists n_1 \in \mathbb{N} : |[a_n] |< ε ~,~~ \forall n \geq  n_1$.

Also I know that $[a_n]\leq a_n < [a_n]+1 $

I tried some inequalities with the above absolute values and the integer part definition but I'm really stuck... Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the sequence converges to 1/2, you have that there exists an $n_0$ such that, for all $n>n_0$, $|a_n-1/2|<1/4$, say.

So, for $n>n_0$, $\frac{1}{4} < a_n < \frac{3}{4}$, and so, for those $n$, $[a_n]=0$.

You can probably finish the proof from there.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So if I write for $n_0=n_1$ I have $[a_n]=0$ since $\forall ε>0 ~~ |[a_n]|=0<ε $ Am i correct? It was so obvious and I was trying inequalites from the integral part without substituting ε !

Comment: @grguest Yes.  This one $n_0$ takes care of everything, since you cannot get smaller than zero...Cheers!

Comment: I havent enough rep to vote up! So Sorry, as you see my first post! You were very helpful! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

around $\frac{1}{2}$ in a sufficiently small neighbourood $N$, $f(x) = [x]$ is a continuous function in $N$. we can assume  all the $a_n$ are in this nbd $N$. now use continuity of $f$.